# Angular Kendo grid header lost sort class after build

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I'm working with angular and kendo grid, Now I have the problem with kendo grid when sort, it happen after build as production, bit it working in development.

> **This is picture in development mode:**
> [image]

> **And this is picture in production mode:**
> [image]

it miss a sign sort, when inspect it I see that in development have class name **k-icon** and **k-i-sort-asc-sm**, but it don't have in production mode, anybody know the problem please help me.

Thank in advance.